# I need to know how to get my program to output the word i typed in and also the new rearranged word using a 2D array

Tags: java

I have a working program which takes the first letter of a word then switches it to the back of the word and adds "ay to the end.  It works fine but I am trying to store the original word and the newWord in a 2D array and output all contents of the array.  I have tried but have come to a dead end.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Decoder1App{
    public static void main(String[]args){

        String word="";
        String newWord="";
        String log[][] = new String[3][2];

        for(int i=0;i<log.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<log[i].length;j++){
               Decoder1 D1 = new Decoder1();`enter code here`
                word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Please enter your word");
                D1.setWord(word);
                D1.compute();
                newWord=D1.getNewWord(); 
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The new word is " + newWord);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What exactly doesn't work?
2. Why are you using a 2d array?
3. If you must use a 2d array:

   ```
   int numOfPairs = 10;

   String[][] array = new String[numOfPairs][2];
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
           array[i] = new String[2];
           array[i][0] = "original word";
           array[i][1] = "rearranged word";
       }   
   }
   ```

Does this give you a hint?

Comment: The word rearranging works fine.  Its just that I need to put the word into a 2D array and get the newWord and get the program to print out all the words and the newWords